# Multiple QX1 syncronized using Sony Camera Remote API

Tags: sony-camera-api

I am looking to synchronize a large number (~30) QX1 cameras such that I can take photos with all of them at very close to the same time (<50mS latency). Does the Remote API allow for controlling multiple QX1s? Is there any API specific limitations that would prevent synchronizing multiple cameras from working?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the remote Camera API does not allow you to connect to multiple cameras.